# PHP echo redirect

Tags: php

I want to echo something in a post after submitting a form, then redirecting the header to cancel the double submit problem. Currently, Output_buffering turned on to allow the redirect to work. here some example code that illustrates the problem. Just make sure Output_buffering is on in php.ini.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   echo "hi";
}

   if (count($_POST) {
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST" name="edit" >
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">edit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect in PHP without use of header method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123470/redirect-in-php-without-use-of-header-method)

Comment: The solution is not very applicable.

Comment: You can't output after headers being sent. That means you have to perform redirect from HTML/Javascript. It looks like Rocky copy-pasted HTML way from same answer and here's JS way. Why do you think these are not applicable?

Comment: Sorry for next explaining earlier. We're redirecting the header to prevent the user from doing a double submit when he refreshes. We want the echo to show, so redirecting it back at it's self is going to remove the echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reverse the order.

On submit:

1. Process yours submit form.
2. Push desired output message into yours session.
3. Redirect to whatever/message page.

On message page show:

1. Retrive message, pushed to session.
2. Cleanup session record.
3. Display message.

It's can be separate page, same page, as with submit for, or any other page.

*Or...*
Do the work with JavaScript and AJAX:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        ...
        if (/all is ok/)
            die(json_encode(array('status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Hi!')));
        else {
            die(json_encode(array('status' => 'err', 'message' => 'I\'m failed!')));
        }
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST" name="edit" >
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">edit</button>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
  $('form').submit(function() {
      var parameters = ...; // collect parameters from form
      $.getJSON('/url-to-script', parameters)
       .success(function(response) {
           if (response.message == "ok")
               alert(response.message);
           else
               alert('Can\'t process input:\n' + response.message);
       })
       .error(function(response) {
           alert('What a terrible failure!');
       });
  });
</script>
```

When .success() fired - you can show supplied message to user via alert/custom modal message box an then make redirect (`document.location = '<?php echo ... ?>'`) or replace form on page with some custom message and link/button to proceed... Lots of variants.

Answer (score 0):

Headers must be sent **BEFORE** any content (that's what `echo` gives).

You could store your message into [session](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) and print it on next request (which would be your follow up redirect).

EXAMPLE:

sessions_init.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
```

post.php

```
<?php
include_once 'sessions_init.php';
// assuming POST succeeded, data is valid, etc
$_SESSION['messages'][] = 'You have been redirected';

header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit();
```

html template:

```
include_once 'sessions_init.php';
// print HTML:
// <html><head>...</head><body>...

foreach($_SESSION['messages'] as $message) {
   print($message);
}

// some other content </body></html>
```